# Min and Max of a date column in a dataframe

Tags: r, date, datetime

I have a data frame column that looks like this:

```
loco 
2018-11-30
2018-10-25
2015-12-10
2020-1-10
2013-2-15
1999-8-17
```

I would just like to find the max date and the min date. 
Here is what I have tried so far

```
print(min(as.character(as.numeric(table3$loco)), na.rm=TRUE))

max(table3$loco, na.rm=true)

max(as.Date('2016-1-1'))

floor(time(table3$loco)[which.min(table3$loco)])

loco %>%
  mutate(earliest_date = pmin(table3$loco))

table3$loco[order(format(as.date(table3$loco), '%m%d%y')) 
[length(dates)]]

min(as.Date(table3$loco))

lapply(table3$loco, max)
```

sample data:

```
   "2018-11-30 07:21:32.605", "2018-11-30 07:21:42.551", "2018-11-30 
    07:21:42.702", 
    "2018-11-30 07:21:42.827", "2018-11-30 07:35:02.107", "2018-11-30 
    07:35:05.309", 
    "2018-11-30 07:37:14.794", "2018-11-30 07:37:36.597", "2018-11-30 
    07:38:51.712", 
    "2018-11-30 07:41:16.125", "2018-11-30 07:41:28.419", "2018-11-30 
    07:41:57.649", 
    "2018-11-30 07:41:57.931", "2018-11-30 07:47:36.917", "2018-11-30 
    07:47:45.759", 
    "2018-11-30 07:47:55.729", "2018-11-30 07:49:43.611", "2018-11-30 
    07:49:46.486", 
    "2018-11-30 07:49:55.789", "2018-11-30 07:52:29.743", "2018-11-30 
    07:53:06.841", 
    "2018-11-30 07:53:47.983", "2018-11-30 07:53:57.526", "2018-11-30 
    07:54:19.956", 
    "2018-11-30 07:54:28.345", "2018-11-30 07:54:38.075", "2018-11-30 
    07:56:43.328", 
    "2018-11-30 07:56:46.107", "2018-11-30 08:04:57.808", "2018-11-30 
    08:04:57.917", 
    "2018-11-30 08:04:58.027", "2018-11-30 08:06:03.055", "2018-11-30 
    08:06:15.762", 
    "2018-11-30 08:06:15.877", "2018-11-30 08:06:15.994", "2018-11-30 
    08:07:33.356", 
    "2018-11-30 08:07:33.576", "2018-11-30 08:07:33.798", "2018-11-30 
    08:07:33.852", 
    "2018-11-30 08:09:15.891", "2018-11-30 08:09:39.825", "2018-11-30 
    08:09:52.997",
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33090847/extract-max-and-min-date-for-a-specific-factor-in-data-frame-r

Answer (score 11):

This is a really simple one.

Convert the column to class `"Date"`:

```
df1$loco <- as.Date(df1$loco)
```

Then try any of

```
min(df1$loco, na.rm = TRUE)
#[1] "1999-08-17"
max(df1$loco, na.rm = TRUE)
#[1] "2020-01-10"

range(df1$loco, na.rm = TRUE)
#[1] "1999-08-17" "2020-01-10"
```

**data.**

```
df1 <- read.table(text = "
loco 
2018-11-30
2018-10-25
2015-12-10
2020-1-10
2013-2-15
1999-8-17                  
", header = TRUE)
```

Comment: Rui Barradas: thank you for your response, however I get this error:
Error in as.date(table3$loco) : Cannot coerce to date format

I should have specified, my data set consists of 199,108 rows. Its a very large data set

Comment: It should be `as.Date`, with uppercase `D`, R is case sensitive. Also, can you post sample data? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(head(df1, 20))`.

Comment: You're right! I have been typing in "as.date" that fixed half of the problem, however, I am getting "NA" as my answers for min and max. I should note, the column has some "null" values. could you please help me solve this

Comment: @shanellealexia Use argument `na.rm = TRUE`. I will edit.

Answer (score 9):

An aproach using `lubridate` package.

Fist, make it reproducible:

```
dates <- data.frame(
  loco = c("2018-11-30", "2018-10-25", "2015-12-10", "2020-1-10", "2013-2-15", "1999-8-17")
  )
```

With data, we can easily perform the two necessary steps: convert to date format and summarize the information you want:

```
# load packages
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

dates %>% 
  # transform to date format with lubridate
  mutate(loco = ymd(loco)) %>% 
  # find min and max
  summarise(min = min(loco),
            max = max(loco))

         min        max
1 1999-08-17 2020-01-10
```

The `lubridate::ymd()` function means "year-month-day".

Beyound this, you can use the same approach, with `lubridate`, to find year min/max too, for example.

```
dates %>% 
  # transform to date format with lubridate
  mutate(loco = ymd(loco)) %>% 
  # find years min and max 
  summarise(min = min(year(loco)),
            max = max(year(loco)))

   min  max
1 1999 2020
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. however my data frame has 199,108 rows, and I cannot type it as a vector format. could you suggest another method?

Comment: How you gone with this @shanellealexia? Did you realize?